# Why does <hr> not do a line break?

Tags: css, html

In the snippet, the two divs should appear below each other, as if seperated thru a line break. Instead, the two divs are kind of next to each other, although the second one is a bit lower than the first. Why is that? How do I get the <hr> to line break?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><title>DoodleDebug</title>
<style>hr{padding:2pt;border:0;}span{float:left;width:40px;}.ColorPlugin{}</style>
</head>
<body>
<div><span style="background-color:#1a63cb">&#160;&#160;&#160;</span>
</div>
<hr>
<div><span style="background-color:#1a63cb">&#160;&#160;&#160;</span>
</div>
```

I'm using the latest Firefox.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is with the `float`ing `span`s. They are taken outside of the normal flow (sort of), so the `div`s end up being 0 height. Well, the second one does, the first one is still a few px high because of the `hr`. Anyways, both `div`s together are much smaller than the `span`s which overflow them. Hence the second `span` is much higher than you would expect. And since `float`s don't overlap each other, the second `span` is placed a little to the right to acommodate that (while still retaining the original vertical position).

A solution then depends on what you want to achieve. I understand that this is a dumbed-down example, so I can't see the bigger picture. My first attempt would be to get rid of the `float` entirely. Most of the time they create more headaches than solutions anyway. Options here are to use `display: inline-block` or just rearranging your HTML somehow.

The second attempt would be to use `clear`, which was [suggested below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8943647/41360) by Brad Christie.

Comment: Not actually the cause of the problem though if you test it. Most browsers parse a `<div><div></div>` as two divs (for the same reason that `<li><li></li>` results in to `<li>` not one inside the other).

Comment: Argh, in our code, the div was closed. Anyway, even closing the div does not yield the wanted layout.

Comment: @Brad - I'm pretty certain that `li` is a special case. Try doing that with a `div` - at least for me, all the browsers displayed the second `div` within the first one.

Comment: @Cedric - You're right, that wasn't the problem. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @BradChristie: are you sure about that? `<li>` has an optional closing tag so it can be implicitly closed by the beginning of the next `<li>` (since they are not allowed to be nested). Since DIV tags can be nested I would expect the first the parser to know that a close tag is missing would be when it found a close tag for whatever followed the div (ie the first close tag that it didn't expect). Thus I'd expect it to just add a close tag to the end giving `<div><div></div></div>`. In short I wouldn't expect div and li to act the same here...

Comment: @Chris: Indeed, you are correct. My apologies for the assumption.

Comment: @BradChristie: no need to apologise since the answer has changed anyway so the original point is irrelevant. I just thought I'd try to make my day a little more productive by helping somebody learn something new. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

It's your float that's interrupting how it displays. You're telling the browser to display the contents next to each other when you specify a float. However, if you apply a `clear:both` on the `<hr>` you get the desired effect:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>DoodleDebug</title>
        <style>hr{padding:2pt;border:0;}span{float:left;width:40px;}.ColorPlugin{}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div><span style="background-color:#1a63cb">&#160;&#160;&#160;</span></div>
        <hr style="clear:both;">
        <div><span style="background-color:#1a63cb">&#160;&#160;&#160;</span></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your're floating your span tags instead of your divs, which are separated by a containing div. Add `div { float:left }` instead to float the actual span containers..

Comment: Indeed. Is span floatable at all? I mean, since it's an inline element I am not even sure float applies to <span>.

Comment: @stefgosselin `<span>` tags are displayed inline naturally, so floating them left does seem moot. Good question, now i have to test that :P

Comment: A `span` can be floated just as well as any other element. [Read the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#float-position). Also, applying `float` to the `div`s would result in them being next to each other, while the OP wants them to be beneath each other.

Comment: @Vilx- you're right, when floated right an element "blocks" itself up to position itself, "block box" they called it in the specs.

Answer (score 1):

hr - is a horizontal line and no line break .. for a line break use

```
<br>
```

Comment: Breaks operate within text. They aren't supposed to be between two block level tags.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is a float:left property in your code, remove it & you have your desired effect.

```
  <style>hr{padding:2pt;border:0;}span{width:40px;clear:both;}.ColorPlugin{}</style>
</head>
<body>
<div><span style="background-color:#1a63cb">&#160;&#160;&#160;</span>
<hr>
<div><span style="background-color:#1a63cb">&#160;&#160;&#160;</span>
```